# What should I learn to build an automatic shift scheduler in Python?

Tags: python

So I've been self-learning Python through this app and I've gotten through the course it offers. I feel like I have a good grasp on the absolute basics of the language, but I still have no idea how to actually use it to solve real problems, ie do actually useful things. I feel like I have a bunch of building blocks but I don't know how to put them together.

So enter my job. I'm a student that works part time and we do weekly schedule requests by paper. It's a giant pain for both us and the supervisors who do the actual scheduling. I was thinking it might be cool to write something to automate the process. It's not so much about the end product though, I'm not being paid enough to write software for my employer. I've just heard everywhere that actually working on projects is the best way to learn and I'm taking this real problem as an opportunity to practice.

So my question is, where should I go from my bare bones knowledge of Python to be able to write something like this? Do I read books? Learn about fancy algorithms? Find something similar and browse its source code? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad, but you may be interesting by developing a client/server application with [DJango](https://www.djangoproject.com/). There is a plugin for scheduling: [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out what you want to your program to do, specifically. Programs are ways to automate processes, and you can not automate something until you know what the process is. You are trying to solve a real-world problem, the first thing you need to do is figure out how this problem is solved today (without your program).

When you try to figure this out, you should not be thinking about how to actually code it in Python, but rather what stepds need to be taken (manually) to achieve what you want. Exactly what would you do if you were doing the scheduling by hand?

Often, people find it useful to describe what a system is actually supposed to do via [use cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case). A use case would describe a single function, feature or process from the perspective of a user of your system. Of course, you don't need to formally write uses cases for your system, but it might help to think of what the system should be doing from a user's perspectice before thinking of the technical details to achieve this.

Once you have concrete features, processes or steps the program need to support, you can start digging into how to actually implement this in Python.